# Unable to decode HTML page with urllib.request

Tags: python, urllib

I've wrote the following piece of code which searches URL and saves the HTML to a text file. However, I have two issues

1. Most importantly, it does not save € and £ in the HTML as this. This is likely a decoding issue which I've tried to fix, but so far without success
2. The following code does not replace the "\n" in the HTML with "". This isn't as important to me, but I am curious as to why it is not working

Any ideas?

```
import urllib.request

while True: # this is an infinite loop
    with urllib.request.urlopen('WEBSITE_URL') as f:
        fDecoded = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        data = str(fDecoded .read()).replace('\n', '') # does not seem to work?

    myfile = open("TestFile.txt", "r+")
    myfile.write(data)
    print ('----------------')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this -

```
fDecoded = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

`fDecoded` is already of type `str` , you are reading the byte string from the request and decoding it into `str` using `utf-8` encoding.

Then after this you cannot call -

```
str(fDecoded .read()).replace('\n', '')
```

`str` has no method `read()` and you do not actually need to convert it to str again. Just do -

```
data = fDecoded.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: Ah I see. Does this mean I am encoding as opposed to decoding?

Comment: ah yees I see it, still finding my way about here. Cheers